# Looping images into ListView

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have some list of image url inside my XML file and I want to display them dynamically using ListView control. I can display those images but the problem is it doesn't loop. My ListView only show the first images.

Here is my coding that I did so far.

```
For i = 0 To 9
    Title = myList(0, i, 0) 'Path of image title inside my array
    Img = myList(0, i, 2) 'Path of image url inside my array
    If Title <> "" Then
        ImageList1.Images.Add("imgKey", New Icon(Img))
        ListView1.Items.Add(Title, "imgKey")
    End If
Next
```

Image title is looping normally but the image doesn't loop so if like I got 3 types of images inside my XML file, when display into ListView, all images are shown with the same image (only the first image - refer to my XML file).

Why is it like that? I'm looking forward your help. Thank you.

Comment: Probably because you are assigning the same image key to all of the images... Try setting it to `"imgKey" & i`

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you so much. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much to `@Steven Doggart` for the solution.

Here is my coding that working all fine now.

```
For i = 0 To 9
    Title = myList(0, i, 0) 'Path of image title inside my array
    Img = myList(0, i, 2) 'Path of image url inside my array
    If Title <> "" Then
        ImageList1.Images.Add("imgKey" & i, New Icon(Img))
        ListView1.Items.Add(Title, "imgKey" & i)
    End If
Next
```